# Postgresql selecting specific rows when using sum() over((

Tags: postgresql, cumulative-sum

I have a list of employees with id and salary, and I want to find the first n employees ordered by id, with cumulative salary sum of x.
Can add cumulative sum with sum() over () as cumsum
but if I use:
Where cumsum < x
That do s not work.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use window function results in `where` or `having`.  Use either a subquery or a CTE to accomplish this:

```
with accumulate as (
  select id, salary, sum(salary) over (order by id) as cum_salary
    from employees
)
select * from accumulate
 where cum_salary < x;
```